# android.view.InflateException:Binary XML file line #223: Binary XML file line #223: Error inflating class

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling

android app is getting terminated.Error is as android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #223: Binary XML file line #223: Error inflating class novumlogic.payment.customview.DashboardContactItem
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)

```
 Error:
            FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: novumlogic.payment, PID: 24369
                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{novumlogic.payment/novumlogic.payment.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #223: Binary XML file line #223: Error inflating class novumlogic.payment.customview.DashboardContactItem
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #223: Binary XML file line #223: Error inflating class novumlogic.payment.customview.DashboardContactItem
                       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #223: Error inflating class novumlogic.payment.customview.DashboardContactItem
                       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                          at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                          at novumlogic.payment.home.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.kt:22)
    at novumlogic.payment.customview.DashboardContactItem.init(DashboardContactItem.kt:50)
                          at novumlogic.payment.customview.DashboardContactItem.<init>(DashboardContactItem.kt:26)
```

Homefragment.kt

```
 package novumlogic.payment.home

     class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
            val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
            initUI(root)
            return root
        }

        private fun initUI(root: View) {
            ViewCompat.setElevation(root.imgSendMoney, 16f)
            ViewCompat.setElevation(root.imgReceiveMoney, 16f)

            root.imgNotification.setOnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Notification List", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            root.cardSendMoney.setOnClickListener {
                startActivity(Intent(activity, SendMoneyActivity::class.java))
            }
            root.cardReceiveMoney.setOnClickListener {
                startActivity(Intent(activity, ReceiveMoneyActivity::class.java))
            }
            root.recyclerBankAccounts.setItemViewCacheSize(0)
            root.recyclerBankAccounts.setHasFixedSize(true)
            root.recyclerBankAccounts.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)

            val bankAccountsAdapter = BankAccountsListAdapter()
            root.recyclerBankAccounts.adapter = bankAccountsAdapter
        }
    }
```

fragment_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                style="@style/BoldTitleStyle"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgLogo"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imgLogo"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgLogo" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgNotification"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_bell_icon" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgBadge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imgNotification"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imgNotification"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/badge" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtBadge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/margin_8"
                android:text="02"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_tiny_8"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/imgBadge"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imgBadge"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/imgBadge"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imgBadge" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_8"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appbar">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMyBankAccounts"
                style="@style/BoldSubTitleStyle"
                android:text="@string/title_my_bank_accounts"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerBankAccounts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardReceiveMoney"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtMyBankAccounts" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardSendMoney"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_8"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_4"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_16"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cardReceiveMoney"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerBankAccounts">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/margin_8">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgSendMoney"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8"
                        android:background="@drawable/send_money_icon"
                        android:padding="@dimen/margin_8"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
                        android:padding="@dimen/margin_8"
                        android:text="@string/msg_send_money"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardReceiveMoney"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_4"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_8"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_16"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/cardSendMoney"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recyclerBankAccounts">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="@dimen/margin_8">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgReceiveMoney"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8"
                        android:background="@drawable/receive_money_icon"
                        android:padding="@dimen/margin_8"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_bold"
                        android:padding="@dimen/margin_8"
                        android:text="@string/msg_receive_money"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorSecondary" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSendMoneyTo"
                style="@style/BoldSubTitleStyle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_22"
                android:text="@string/label_send_money_to"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cardSendMoney" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSendMoneyToViewAll"
                style="@style/BoldSubTitleStyle"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                android:text="@string/label_view_all"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_small_14"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/txtSendMoneyTo"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/cardReceiveMoney" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/linearSendMoneyTo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_16"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtSendMoneyTo">

                <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <novumlogic.payment.customview.DashboardContactItem
                        android:id="@+id/imgAddContact"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8"
                        app:contactImage="@drawable/ic_add_circle"
                        app:contactName="Add New"
                        app:hasBackgroundRing="true"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/contactItem1"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <novumlogic.payment.customview.DashboardContactItem
                        android:id="@+id/contactItem1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8"
                        app:contactImage="@drawable/ic_avatar"
                        app:contactName="Alice"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/contactItem2"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgAddContact"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <novumlogic.payment.customview.DashboardContactItem
                        android:id="@+id/contactItem2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8"
                        app:contactImage="@drawable/ic_avatar"
                        app:contactName="Bob"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/contactItem3"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/contactItem1"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <novumlogic.payment.customview.DashboardContactItem
                        android:id="@+id/contactItem3"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8"
                        app:contactImage="@drawable/ic_avatar"
                        app:contactName="Emily"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgViewMore"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/contactItem2"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgViewMore"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/contactItem3"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right" />

                </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/txtUtilities"
                style="@style/BoldSubTitleStyle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_22"
                android:text="@string/label_utilities"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearSendMoneyTo" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_8"
                app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_16"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txtUtilities">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_rect"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_8"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_8">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtMobileUtility"
                        style="@style/AppTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_utility_phone"
                        android:text="@string/label_mobile" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtElectricityUtility"
                        style="@style/AppTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_utility_electricity"
                        android:text="@string/label_electricity" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtBroadbandUtility"
                        style="@style/AppTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"                            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_utility_broadband"
                        android:text="@string/label_broadband" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtGasUtility"
                        style="@style/AppTextStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_utility_gas"
                        android:text="@string/label_gas" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Dashboardcontactotem.kt

package novumlogic.payment.customview

class DashboardContactItem : ConstraintLayout {
    var contactImage: Drawable? = null
    lateinit var contactName: String
    var hasBackgroundRing = false
    var textSize = 14

```
constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
    getAttributes(attrs)
    init()
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    getAttributes(attrs)
    init()
}

private fun getAttributes(attrs: AttributeSet) {
    val attributes = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.DashboardContactItem,
            0, 0)
    try {
        contactImage = attributes.getDrawable(R.styleable.DashboardContactItem_contactImage)
        contactName = attributes.getString(R.styleable.DashboardContactItem_contactName)
        hasBackgroundRing = attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.DashboardContactItem_hasBackgroundRing, false)
        textSize = attributes.getInteger(R.styleable.DashboardContactItem_hasBackgroundRing, 14)
    } finally {
        attributes.recycle()
    }
}

private fun init() {
    val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_contact_dashboard, null)
    addView(view)
    if (contactImage != null) {
        view.imgContact.setImageDrawable(contactImage)
        if (hasBackgroundRing) {
            view.imgContact.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.add_circle_icon)
        }
    }
    view.txtContactName.text = contactName
    view.txtContactName.setCustomTextSize(textSize.toFloat())
}

private fun TextView.setCustomTextSize(size: Float) {
    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size)
}
```

}

```
item.contact.dashboard.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_8">

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/imgContact"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_40"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/size_40"
        app:actualImageResource="@drawable/ic_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:placeholderImage="@drawable/ic_avatar"
        app:roundAsCircle="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtContactName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTertiary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imgContact" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Kindly check it i have added

Comment: @MikeM.kindly check it

Comment: Please post the layout for `R.layout.item_contact_dashboard` file.

Comment: Error inflating class novumlogic.payment.customview.DashboardContactItem
There is likely an error with the XML for this view

Comment: @VishalArora added please check it

Comment: ok boss .. on it

Comment: Try passing `this` in `View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_contact_dashboard, null)` instead of `null`.   `View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_contact_dashboard, this)`

Comment: @VishalArora No I have added Fresco.initialize(this) in Appcontroller. It solved my problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added **Fresco.initialize(this)** in Appcontroller. It solved my problem .

```
AppController.kt
Class AppController : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Fresco.initialize(this)
    }
}
```